# Is $\int \frac{e^{z^2}}{z^3} dz=\pi i$? I got $2 \pi i$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html)

[image]

[image]

The answer key says $\pi i$. By Cauchy's Integral Formula 5.1 for $f''(w)$, I think the answer is $2 \pi i$:

$$\int_{\square} \frac{e^{z^2}}{z^3} dz = \pi i \frac{d^2}{dz^2} e^{z^2}|_{z=0} $$ [=](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E2%2Fdz%5E2%20e%5E%7Bz%5E2%7D,%20z%3D0) $ \pi i (2) = 2 \pi i$.

I also tried on Wolfram Alpha [1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E(2*pi)%20(e%5E(%7B4e%5E%7Bi*t%7D%7D)%5E2)%2F((4e%5E%7Bi*t%7D)%5E3)%204*i*e%5E%7Bi*t%7D%20dt) [2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E(2*pi)%20(e%5E(%7Be%5E%7Bi*t%7D%7D)%5E2)%2F((e%5E%7Bi*t%7D)%5E3)%20i*e%5E%7Bi*t%7D%20dt) for circles which I believe are homotopic to the square. I think I get the same answer with Residue Thm 9.10 and Prop 9.11:

$$\int_{\square} \frac{e^{z^2}}{z^3} dz = 2 \pi i \frac{1}{2!} \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{d^2}{dz^2} (z-0)^3 \frac{e^{z^2}}{z^3}$$

$$ = \pi i (2)$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $2\pi i$ is the correct answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks! ^-^ Post as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is $2\pi i$. I will suggest another method: expand the exponential in a power series and look at the coefficient of $\frac 1 z$. This shows that the residue at $0$ is $1$ so the integral is  $2\pi i$.