# Is $\int_{C[-2i,r]} \frac{dz}{z^2+1} = 0 , 1 < r < 3$? I got $-\pi$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html)  Exer 4.33

[image]

It is given that $r \ne 1,3$ and that the answer is $0 \ \forall r$. I got $0 \ \forall \ r \in(0,1) \cup (3,\infty)$ and $-\pi \ \forall \ r \in(1,3)$. I have 2 solutions:

1. $$\int_{C[-2i,r]} \frac{dz}{z^2+1} = \frac{-i}{2}\int_{C[-2i,r]} \frac{1}{z-i} - \frac{1}{z+i}dz = \frac{-i}{2}[0-2\pi i] = - \pi$$
2. $$\int_{C[-2i,r]} \frac{dz}{z^2+1} = \int_{C[-2i,r]} \frac{\frac{1}{z-i}}{z+i} dz = 2\pi i \frac{1}{z-i}|_{z=-i} = 2\pi i \frac{1}{-2i} = - \pi$$

I even computed $-\pi$ on Wolfram Alpha for [$r=2$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20((2*ie%5E%7Bit%7D)%20%2F%20((-2i%2B2*e%5E%7Bit%7D)%5E2%2B1))%20dt,%20t%20%3D%200%20to%202*pi), [$r=2.5$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20((2.5*ie%5E%7Bit%7D)%20%2F%20((-2i%2B2.5*e%5E%7Bit%7D)%5E2%2B1))%20dt,%20t%20%3D%200%20to%202*pi) and [$r=e$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20((e*ie%5E%7Bit%7D)%20%2F%20((-2i%2Be*e%5E%7Bit%7D)%5E2%2B1))%20dt,%20t%20%3D%200%20to%202*pi).

And yet the answer is simply $0$

[image]

Why is it 0 please?

Note: Textbook has been previously wrong: [Is $\int \frac{e^{z^2}}{z^3} dz=\pi i$? I got $2 \pi i$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860138)

Comment: What does the notation $C[-2i, r]$ mean?

Comment: @User8128 circle centred at -2i with radius r. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right and your textbook is wrong: the answer **is** $-\pi$ if $r\in(1,3)$.